# how can i delete a attribute's endpoint in AWS pinpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

Using AWS pinpoint, the endpoint have some customs attributes. With "UpdateEndpoint" https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/pinpoint/update-endpoint.html
it's possible to update the attribute, but how to remove one ?

Basic endpoint with attribute "1248" and "040110" :

```
{"Address": "+1123456789", "ApplicationId": "XXX", "Attributes": {"1248": ["sim", "spa", "simaj"], "040110": ["sim", "spa"]}, "ChannelType": "SMS", "CohortId": "73"}
```

What i want once the attribute "040110" removed

```
{"Address": "+1123456789", "ApplicationId": "XXX", "Attributes": {"1248": ["sim", "spa", "simaj"]}, "ChannelType": "SMS", "CohortId": "73"}
```

Chapgpt test, I tested with `"040110": null`

tested with null, empty string, empty array

Answer (score 1):

confirmed by our AWS support guy, once created the attribute cannot be deleted.
You can put a empty array to fake the null value.
or recreate the endpoint without the attribute.